# how to vertically center responsive layout, and fix padding on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a page with a html5 game in an iframe - it is vertical sized 3:4, and there is one line of text below it.

- it vertically scales and stays in proportion 3:4 ok - BUT the game and text does not sit vertically centered... it sits slightly high. any ideas how to fix, so it's all  vertically centered?
- at smaller sizes (and for mobile) i wanted to get it sit centered with 50px of padding on the left and right of the game. but on mobile even with the padding set to the media query it does not show...  any ideas how to fix?

Html and css code below:

thanks -

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.iframe-container {
  /* Define your desired aspect ratio here (e.g., 16:9) */
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;
  height: 80%;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16px;
  color: orange;
}


/* Media query for smaller screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #text {
    display: none;
    /* Hide the text on screens below 600px width */
  }
  .iframe-container {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game test layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="blue">
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe style="border:5px inset silver;" src="https://rajeevbasu.com/projects/test/" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Copyright information here 2024. <img src="images/button.png"> <img src="images/button.png"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything I've tried, including current code is above.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Provide a working example here please. And if you do, change the colours, I just got a 5k eye trauma.

Comment: thanks, i included all the code i have tried above. should i include any other context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue relates to the [CSS box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). When you set the width and/or height of an element, by default, they specify width of the **content area** of the element, **excluding** any padding or borders. Your iframe has a 5px border which is not included in the width and height you have specified. So the visible height your iframe, including the border, is 100% of its parent element, plus the 5px top border, plus the 5px bottom border, so it appears to be 10px too large, and not quite in the centre. Same story with the width.

The best solution is to set [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) on the iframe. This setting means that your specified height and width will **include** any padding and borders.

```
iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The next issue is the default margins on the `p` element which contains the copyright text. Just set the margin to zero.

```
#text p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The final issue is that on narrow screens, your combination of a height rule with an aspect-ratio rule on the iframe container causes its width to be greater than 100%. That’s why it spills over the sides. On smaller screens you’ll need to switch from `height: 80%` to `width: 80%`. This also negates the need for padding in the iframe container.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .iframe-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

.iframe-container {
    aspect-ratio: 3 / 4;
    height: 80%;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:5px inset silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 16px;
    color: orange;

}

#text p {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .iframe-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
  #text {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Novak_Djokovic_at_ATP_2015.jpg" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <p>&copy; Copyright information here.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about box-sizing and read up about it. The thing is, I'm not sure this has solved the positioning problem. Even in your example - everything on the page still sits a bit high. I wonder if it is something to do with right now the code is not taking into account BOTH the game iframe AND the text line below it in order to calculate what to collectively vertically center? - just a theory, not sure if it is, or how to address if any ideas?

Comment: You have not described your design goals. How do you want it to appear? Do you want the `iframe` to be in the absolute centre, with the copyright text underneath, but only on larger screens?

Comment: yes - on big screens: the goal is to have ALL the elements collectively vertically centered on the page - that includes both the game part and the text line below it. on smaller screens and mobile: the text line div is hidden, and I want the game part to be centered with a bit of padding (e.g. 50px)on both the left and right, so it's not hitting the edges. right now on mobile it bleeds into the sides and is oversized and the padding is not working, but I am not sure why. Any ideas on these? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying your design goals. I have updated my answer to hopefully deal with all those issues.

Comment: thank you. The vertical align works perfect, helpful to learn about the default padding around the text which may have been contributing to  off center. The page is also working well on mobile, sizing neatly by changing the %size in relation to width instead of height. The one thing is, if you look at the page but make the browser window small - black bars appear. The 3:4 aspect ratio to the iframe container was used to prevent this, but doesn't seem to work when v small? https://www.rajeevbasu.com/projects/test/page.html

Comment: You’re right, the solution isn’t perfect. But the languages of the web aren’t perfect either; there are all sorts of things we’d like to be able to do on the web, but we can’t. For example, we can use `object-size: contain` on an image to make it perfectly fit a container of any shape, but we can't use that on an iframe. You may be able to improve the solution by further tailoring the media query; for example, you could try adding an `orientation: portrait` condition.